# Sorting a JSON file in React, component not rerendering onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, sorting, render

I am working on a E-Commerce site in React that displays a list of items that are derived from a JSON file. The JSON file includes info such as the price, model, image, etc.

I'm trying to add "Sort by: Price" functionality to the site. The function I have right now works correctly in sorting the JSON data:

```
import products from "../data/products.json";

function Shop(){
    const [items, setItems] = useState();

function sortProducts() {
    setItems(products.sort(sortByProperty("price")));
  }

function sortProductsReverse(){
    setItems(products.sort(sortByProperty("price")).reverse);
}

return ( 
{products.map((product) => (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Product {...product} />
            </React.Fragment> )
        }
}
```

`sortByProperty` does the sorting logic from lowest to highest, `sortProducts` sorts from lowest to highest, `sortProductsReverse` sorts from highest to lowest. `Product` is the component that takes in the JSON data and displays everything.

When the page is first loaded, all the products are displayed correctly without being sorted. When a button is onClicked to `sortProducts` or `sortProductsReverse`, it works. However, it works only once. The items cannot be sorted/re-rendered again.

I think I'm missing something in `items` useState, but I'm not sure what I should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your component to rerender, you need to set the state with a **new object reference**, React then compares previous and current state, and if they are not equal, it rerenders the component.

In your case, `items` is initially `undefined`, and when you set it as `products`, the component rerenders.

After that, everytime you call `products.sort`, it sets `items` the same object from before, because `sort` method in JavaScript mutates the original object, but doesn't return a new one.

To solve the problem, everytime call `setItems` with a new object:

`setItems([...products].sort(sortByProperty("price")));`

Comment: This solution is not working for me, nothing changes/renders when I try it this way. 'products' is the JSON data, am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I managed to fix it! setItems([...products], products.sort(sortByProperty("price")));

does the trick. Thank you, .sort needs to be called on "products"